# What is the name of the (possibly well-known) class of $\pi$-monolithic compact spaces?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

A compact space $X$ is called  ${\it \pi-monolithic}$ if whenever a surjective continuous mapping $f:X\rightarrow K$ where $K$ is a compact metric space there exists a compact metric space $T\subseteq X$ such that $f(T)=K$.

Perhaps this class of compact spaces has been studied (for example, in articles by R.Pol or T.A. Chapman). But I couldn't find a reference about this class of spaces.Therefore, for now we call this class as a class of $\pi$-monolithic compact spaces.

${\bf Question.}$ What is the name of the (possibly well-known) class of $\pi$-monolithic compact spaces?

Comment: Do you have any non-trivial examples?

Comment: For example, a monolithic compact space (or a dyadic  compact space) is $\pi$-monolithic.

Comment: @AlexanderOsipov could you elaborate/give a reference on why monolithic compact spaces satisfy this property? (I'm only familiar with the definition of monolithicity in terms of cardinal characteristics)

Comment: Let $f:X->K$ be a continuous mapping $X$ onto a compact metric space $K$. Let $S$ be a countable dense subset of $K$. Then $T=\overline{f^{-1}(S)}$ is a compact metric space    and $f(T)=K$.